# How I can make a request with params from finagle client?

Tags: scala, finagle

I’m getting started with a Finagle server (twitter/finagle):

```
import com.twitter.finagle.{Http, Service}
import com.twitter.util.{Await, Future}
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http._

object Server extends App {
  val service = new Service[HttpRequest, HttpResponse] {
    def apply(req: HttpRequest): Future[HttpResponse] =
      Future.value(new DefaultHttpResponse(
        req.getProtocolVersion, HttpResponseStatus.OK))
  }
  val server = Http.serve(":8080", service)
  Await.ready(server)
}
```

Client (twitter/finagle):

```
import com.twitter.finagle.{Http, Service}
import com.twitter.util.{Await, Future}
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http._

object Client extends App {
  val client: Service[HttpRequest, HttpResponse] =
    Http.newService("localhost:8080")
  val request =  new DefaultHttpRequest(
    HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.GET, "/")
  val response: Future[HttpResponse] = client(request)
  response onSuccess { resp: HttpResponse =>
    println("GET success: " + resp)
  }
  Await.ready(response)
}
```

How do I send data like `Map("data_id" -> 5)` from the client to the server? And where in the server do I receive it? Do I have to add a callback to the server?

I haven’t found it by searching. If you can give me a link with an example, that will be enough.

Comment: downvoting after the year without comment, lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finagle is a very thin library. That means that you'll have to handle most of the "magic" by yourself.

To make the request with parameters from the Client, I use these helper methods:

```
  def buildUri(base: String, path: String, params: Map[String, String] = Map.empty): String = {
    val p = if (params.isEmpty) ""
    else params map { case (k,v) => urlEncode(k) + "=" + urlEncode(v) } mkString ("?", "&", "")
    base + path + p
  }

  def urlEncode(url: String): String = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8")
```

And then I call it like this:

```
val url = buildUri(baseAddress, path, defaultParams ++ params)
val req = RequestBuilder().url(url).setHeader("Accept", "*/*").buildGet
client(req)
```

As for the server you have to do basically the same thing and parse the parameters by hand. Either using `java.net.URI` or even `org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.QueryStringDecoder`.

Of course you can also use `URI` and `QueryStringEncoder` to encode as well, instead of using my helper methods.

That said, if you want to do that on higher level, you can use one of these libraries above Finagle:

- https://github.com/fwbrasil/zoot
- http://finatra.info/ (this is for the server part only)

Comment: Seems like i have to read much more, thanks, i try and can get params on server side!

Comment: Glad it worked! Finagle is a powerful tool but it with a steep learning curve.